# Disqus Forum - such thing, or even possible?

Tags: disqus

Is it possible to create a simple forum or even a classified plugin using the disqus API - is there anything out there currently? I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seen a few people using disqus as a forum and I'm actually planning to do so myself.
There's www.moot.it which can be used as a commenting system and also as a forum, but I don't quite like a few things about it.
Regarding setting disqus up as a forum board, you need to make a small app that would allow your users to create pages / topics / posts, whatever you want to call them.

Comment: Roger, not very familiar with stackoverflow overall xD